# Ошибка: allocated an object of abstract class type 'StringListModel'

Tags: c++, qt, qabstracttablemodel, qabstractlistmodel

Я видел, что экземпляр абстрактного класса создавать нельзя. Но я делаю всё по официальной документации: **https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/model-view-programming.html#using-models-and-views**

Объясните мне пожалуйста почему появляется ошибка. И нужно ли мне переопределить все виртуальные функции, присутствующие внутри StringListModel? Если да, то поясните почему.

Не судите строго, только начал разбираться в программировании модели/представления.

**main.cpp файл**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "stringlistmodel.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QAbstractListModel>
#include <QModelIndex>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QStringList numbers;
    numbers << "One" << "Two" << "Three" << "Four" << "Five";

    QAbstractItemModel *model = new StringListModel(numbers);
    QListView *view = new QListView;
    view->setModel(model);
    view->show();

    QTableView *tableView = new QTableView;
    tableView->setModel(model);
    tableView->show();
    tableView->setSelectionModel(view->selectionModel());

    return a.exec();
}
```

**stringlistmodel.h**

```
#ifndef STRINGLISTMODEL_H
#define STRINGLISTMODEL_H

#include <QAbstractListModel>

class StringListModel : public QAbstractItemModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    StringListModel(const QStringList &strings, QObject *parent = 0)
        : QAbstractItemModel(parent), stringList(strings) {}

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const;
    QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;
    Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex &index) const;
    bool setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value,int role = Qt::EditRole);
    bool insertRows(int position, int rows, const QModelIndex &index = QModelIndex());
    bool removeRows(int position, int rows, const QModelIndex &index = QModelIndex());
private:
    QStringList stringList;
};

#endif // STRINGLISTMODEL_H
```

Comment: Судя по тексту ошибки, в Вашем классе остались чисто виртуальные функции. Их необходимо переопределить, чтобы они перестали быть чисто виртуальными. Тогда класс перестанет быть абстрактным.

Comment: Приводите текст ошибки полностью. Там обычно пишется, чего не хватает.

Comment: ..\text_Model_3\main.cpp:17:60: error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type 'StringListModel'
     QAbstractItemModel *model = new StringListModel(numbers);

Comment: Это полный текст ошибки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я прошу прощения за ответ вопросом на вопрос - для чего Вы используете `QAbstractItemModel` в качестве интерфейса? Если Вам нужно реализовать модель таблицы, то следует наследоваться от `QAbstractTableModel`, тогда не нужно переопределять методы `index` и `parent`, но, в любом случае, Вы еще должны переопределить `columnCount`.
Ответ: Вы не переопределили некоторые чисто виртуальные методы.

Comment: Использую QAbstractItemModel, потому что я хочу реализовать не только модель таблицы, но и простой список элементов, а так же древовидную структуру в будущем.  А QAbstractTableModel предоставляет более специализированный интерфейс, чемQAbstractItemModel. И к тому же неподходит для работы с с древовидными представлениями.

Так, хорошо, я не переопределил, некоторые виртуальные методы. Есть вопрос, как это сделать. Можете пожалуйста объяснить, либо где можно найти подробную информацию как и зачем это делается.

Comment: Точно так же, как Вы переопределяете `rowCount` и `data`. Можете посмотреть в исходных кодах как они переопределяют эти методы и сделать что-то похожее. Или взять, например, последнюю версию примера qt6/qtserialbus/examples/serialbus/can/can.pro с моими правками.

Comment: data - отвечает за заполнение представления,   
rowCount, columnCount - число строк, столбцов,  
index - возвращает QModelIndex для выбранной ячейки,  
Вот с parent все сложнее намного, и Вам вряд ли удастся нормально совместить его реализацию для представления в дереве и таблице.

Comment: Спасибо вам за развернутый ответ. Ну тогда сделаю отдельно реализацию для представления дерева.

Comment: Да, и дерево наследуйте от QAbstractItemModel. Вот хороший пример - https://github.com/dridk/QJsonModel
А таблицу лучше от QAbstractTableModel.